# I want to access all the files and images present in them

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to get all the images and the name of file name containing them in something like hashmap and want to show them in my flutter application using grid view..

if anyone have any clue how to do this, will be helpful for me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to add more information on what you mean by "get all the images and the name of file name containing them in something like hashmap". It's unclear.

Comment: @ishaan, I am trying to make a mobile gallery type application. so ,want to get a list of all images from internal and as well as external memory and also the name of file containing them.

Comment: Might want to take a look at https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-io/dart-io-library.html , till someone who has solved something similar helps.